# what is a "ReferenceError" and how to fix it?

Tags: javascript

I'm getting the following error in my notify.js :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Notify is not defined

**here is the code in my js**

```
function onPermissionGranted() {
    doNotification("Notification Allowed", "You will now receive notifications once your checking is complete.")
}
function onPermissionDenied() {
    console.warn("Permission has been denied by the user")
}
function doNotification(t, e) {
    new Notify(t,{
        body: e
    }).show()
}
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    if ("" != $("#live").val() || "" != $("#cclist").val())
        return "You're about to leave this page. Are you done saving your live results?"
}
,
Notify.needsPermission && Notify.requestPermission(onPermissionGranted, onPermissionDenied);
var timer, list, tlist, tw = 191, stop = !0, ct = 0, akey = "10001|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
```

when I run the page I got the console error.

Comment: Have you correctly included the API script, and in the right order ?

Comment: I removed your sub-question "I also wanted to run the notify.js using `windows.onload` but how should I code it?". This would be a different post on StackOverflow and it probably already has an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Notify` class is most likely in a different file that is not referred in the file where you get this error.

The error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: *[ref]* is not defined

is an error telling you your code has a reference that cannot be understood by the JavaScript interpreter and that it can't... well... interpret it. `[ref]` is the name of the reference triggering the error. It can be an unknown class, an undefined variable or an undefined function. Check for typos and make sure the class is both declared and included.

Also, make sure that the imported JavaScript file of your class is imported **before** the script using it :

```
<script src="path/notify.js" type="text/javascript" />
<script src="path/usingnotify.js" type="text/javascript" />
```

would work, whereas

```
<script src="path/usingnotify.js" type="text/javascript" />
<script src="path/notify.js" type="text/javascript" />
```

would not.